# Converting a MySQL query to Symfony doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have this `MySQL` query that I want to convert to a query understood by Doctrine.

```
SELECT name from users where project = 10 and (classification = 12 
or classification is null)
```

So I've tried to convert that in Doctrine but it is not working.

```
$query->AndWhere('users.classification = :classification');
$query->setParameter(':classification', $classification);
$query->orWhere('users.classification = :classification');
$query->setParameter(':classification', null);
```

I've tried to use the expression `$query->expr()` I did not succeed

Comment: Iwan answer is valid, still, you can find a [good lecture here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/and-where-or-where) about the use of `where`, `andWhere` and `orWhere`. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group multiple where statements in parentheses you can use `orx` and `andx`

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
    'users.classification = :classification',
    'users.classification IS NULL'
))
->setParameter(':classification', $classification);
```

Or with doctrine expression:

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('user.classification', ':classification'),
    $queryBuilder->expr()->isNull('users.classification')
))
->setParameter(':classification', $classification);
```

Doctrine docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class